# Should we use supervisors to keep processes running in Docker containers?

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker to run a java REST service in a container. If I were outside of a container then I might use a process manager/supervisor to ensures that the java service restarts if it encounters a strange one-off error. I see some posts about using supervisord inside of containers but it seems like they're focused mostly on running multiple services, rather than just keeping one up.

What is the common way of managing services that run in containers? Should I just be using some built in Docker stuff on the container itself rather than trying to include a process manager?

Answer (score 5):

You should not use a process supervisor inside your Docker container for a single-service container. Using a process supervisor effectively hides the health of your service, making it more difficult to detect when you have a problem.

You should rely on your container orchestration layer (which may be Docker itself, or a higher level tool like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes) to restart the container if the service fails.

With Docker (or Docker Swarm), this means setting a restart policy on the container.

Comment: (A multi-process supervisor also tends to swallow its managed processes' logs, so instead of just running `docker logs` you need to dig around in the container's temporary filesystem.)